# Writing Inside a text file using Scanner Class

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I have Come across so many programmes of how to read a text file using `Scanner` in Java. Following is some dummy code of Reading a text file in Java using `Scanner`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("10_Random");

    try {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            int i = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        sc.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

But, please anyone help me in "Writing" some text (i.e. String or Integer type text) inside a `.txt` file using `Scanner` in java. I don't know how to write that code.

Comment: `Scanner` is for reading, not for writing.

Comment: consider `OutputStream` for your purpose

Answer (score 9):

`Scanner` can't be used for writing purposes, only reading. I like to use a `BufferedWriter` to write to text files.

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
out.write("Write the string to text file");
out.newLine();
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that Scanner is for reading only. I will use this BufferedWriter class. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 4):

`Scanner` is for reading purposes. You can use `Writer` class to write data to a file.

For Example:

```
Writer wr = new FileWriter("file name.txt");
wr.write(String.valueOf(2))  // write int
wr.write("Name"); // write string

wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that Scanner is for reading only. I will use this Writer class. Thanks a lot. :)